# Is it possible to insert new keys in middle of anchor array using YAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have YAML file with anchor array like this.

```
sammy: &as
  - a
  - c
```

And now I want to add new key, but in following manner:

```
mobile:
  <<: *as # Want to add new element in between a & c
  # i.e.
  # The new mobile should be
  # a b c
```

Is it possible?
Note: I'm using ysets to retrieve these keys in app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. The reason for that is that the anchored element, that your alias `as` refers to, has to be a mapping according to the [specification for merge keys](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html).

And your element (i.e. the value for `sammy`) is a sequence, not a mapping, so this is not going to work.

This is also the reason why checking:

```
sammy: &as
  - a
  - c
mobile:
  <<: *as
```

[online](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=sammy%3A%20%26as%0A%20%20-%20a%0A%20%20-%20c%0Amobile%3A%0A%20%20%3C%3C%3A%20*as&type=json) gives you an error.

The only way around this would be to do something like:

```
sammy: &as
  1: a
  3: c
mobile:
  <<: *as
  2: b
```

And then use the values of `mobile` sorted by its keys.

Comment: Is it atleast possible to xor? Like *as - a

Comment: @user2215912 What you can do is make the value a mapping, I updated my answer.

Comment: I used this solution. Thank you!